# CSS diagonal gradient with a more smooth transit

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have never used gradient before and i am trying to achieve something very similar to this

[image]

as you see this bar has the same color and left and right and just to the right of middle it has some kind of brighter gradient and i have been trying to get kind of the same look trying to focus on the gradient part first with this

```
    export class LeaderboardBar extends React.Component<Props, State>
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
            <div id="leaderboard-bar-left">
            </div>
            <div id="leaderboard-bar-right">
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and this css

```
    #leaderboard-bar-left {
    width: 60%;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, #1e2933 50%, #39424B 30%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#leaderboard-bar-right {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #1e2933;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

but this only give me this kind of gradient

[image]

i cant seem to get the transit to become brighter the further to the break in the diagonal gradient how is this achieved?

Comment: drop the percentage statements "background: linear-gradient(to top left, #1e2933, #39424B);" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try multiple gradient like this:

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#1e2933,#1e2933) right/120px 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 47%, #1e2933 52%) calc(100% - 118px) 0/40% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to right, #1e2933 , #39424B 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
</div>
```